# pymongo - Invalid document cannot encode object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to find an image with the closest colour in the database given an image using the euclidean algorithm (since I do not really care about the distance, I omit the sqrt). Each item in the database contains the fields `r`, `g`, `b`.

Heres my code to retrieve the result:

```
r, g, b = utilities.get_avg_rgb(match_image.convert('RGB'))

res = self.database_collection.aggregate([
    {'$set': {
        'diff': {
            '$sum': [{'$pow': [{'$sub': ['$r', r]}, 2]},
                     {'$pow': [{'$sub': ['$g', g]}, 2]},
                     {'$pow': [{'$sub': ['$b', b]}, 2]}]
        }
    }},
    {'$sort': {'diff', 1}},
    {'$limit': 1}
])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'bson.errors.InvalidDocument'>, InvalidDocument("cannot encode object: {1, 'diff'}, of type: <class 'set'>"), <traceback object at 0x0F5483C8>)
```

I think it says I am trying to encode an object with class `set` which it cannot do so (?) but I could not find the reason.

May I know why this happens and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I believe the $sort operator takes  `<field1>: <sort order>`, where you have  `<field1>, <sort order>`. Try `{'$sort': {'diff': 1}}`

Comment: @It'sNotMe Yup that solved the problem, but now I am getting a new exception `<class 'tuple'>: (<class 'pymongo.errors.OperationFailure'>, OperationFailure("Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'"), <traceback object at 0x0EBFFC60>)`

Comment: @It'sNotMe Thanks alot for seeing that for me! I will try to work on from here, do you mind making it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `$sort` operator takes `<field1>: <sort order>`, where you have `<field1>, <sort order>`. Try `{'$sort': {'diff': 1}}`.

Also, `$set` is an [update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and does not appear to be supported in the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/).